# How to set a specific input from a user I.e 8 digits only?

Tags: java, string, integer

Hi so I have had a look around and I cannot find the answer I am looking for..

What I am looking for is a way to set a requirement when using the scanner(in) method. I am making a bank account app now for a project and when I ask the user to enter an 8 digit account number I want to be able to restrict the users input to exactly 8 digits with errors popping up if they enter above or below that set requirement?

I seen something like Integer.toString().length but don't know how to use it and if it will even work? Any help will do thank you

Comment: Use a `Scanner`, read a `String`, test if that `String` matches your `Pattern` (`\\d{8}`).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Thanks Elliot not trying to be rude but could you explain a bit more I am pretty new to programming and that has just went straight over my head haha 

Comment: What's that about like joe can someone not just ask for a bit of help I thought this was a community to help each other out if possible

Comment: We are a question-and-answer site, not a code writing service.  You cannot simply dump some requirements and expect us to code it for you.  May I suggest you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Ok then I will rephrase the question as this is what I am asking not for you to do it for me... is there a way I can restrict the input from a user to set parameters as stated above in java? and if so what methods or code should I be looking into? Now does this pass as a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you start by declaring scanner object:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Some message to user so he/she would know what to do:

```
System.out.println("enter your account numer");
int account_number = in.nextInt();
```

Now just check if the numer is 8 digit.

```
if (new Integer(account_number).toString().length == 8)
System.out.println("Correct account numer);
else
System.out.println("Something went wrong 404");
```

Comment: Ah I see yes I read about the integer.toString method but couldn't quite work out how I could use it in my program. By putting it in a if statement it will check the users input and test that against the required length ==8? Thank you Getriax